# tikzDevice package not loading in R GUI

Tags: r

I'm having trouble loading the tikz package on my R GUI:

```
> require(tikzDevice)
Loading required package: tikzDevice
Warning message:
In fun(libname, pkgname) : 

tikzDevice: No appropriate LaTeX compiler could be found.
Access to LaTeX is required in order for the TikZ device
to produce output.

The following places were tested for a valid LaTeX compiler:

    the global option: tikzLatex
    the environment variable: R_LATEXCMD
    the environment variable: R_PDFLATEXCMD
    the global option: latexcmd
    the PATH using the command: pdflatex
    the PATH using the command: latex
    the PATH using the command: /usr/texbin/pdflatex

If you have a working LaTeX compiler, try one of the
following solutions:

    Set the path to your compiler as the value of either latexcmd or
    tikzLatex in .Rprofile using options().

    Set the path to your compiler as the value of either R_LATEXCMD or
    R_PDFLATEXCMD in .Renviron.

    Ensure the folder containing your compiler is included in PATH.
```

Now the weird part is that I'm able to run my script just fine when I use the terminal. Any idea of what is happening with the GUI?

I'm running R 3.3.2 on a MacOS 10.12.3. I use TexShop, which I downloaded with MacTEX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can easily be solved thusly:

```
options(tikzLatex = "PATH")
```

Substitute PATH by the path of your LaTeX compiler. You can find that out by typing the following in the Terminal, for Mac users:

```
which pdflatex
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be useful to other Mac users that have upgraded their OS recently. This worked for me and was not a problem related to the tikzDevice package but to latex not being able to compile because the path to compile pdflatex has been deleted by Mac (see [MacTex f.a.q.](https://www.tug.org/mactex/elcapitan.html) on el Capitan for the full explanation because that's when apple started preventing users to install latex items in usr/ folder).
I suggest the following:

1. Download and install MacTex
2. Specify path to compile in texshop/texworks instead of usr/bin put /Library/TeX/texbin
3. Check now that tikzDevice is working in you GUI (should be now !)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this page after hitting the exact same issue / exact same output, but under `Windows 11`.

i use `tinytex`. So what solved it for me was to issue

`options("tikzLatex"=tinytex:::win_app_dir('TinyTeX', 'bin', 'win32', 'pdflatex.exe'))`

right at the top of my document, in the very first setup chunk, before calling `library(tikzDevice)`. I've tried many other things, but kept running into the error above... and really drove me crazy!